# PHP/jQuery: Retrieve new sortable value

Tags: php, jquery, variables, echo, jquery-ui-sortable

I know there are many guides on how to retrieve the new value from a JQuery sortable function. But it doesn't work like I want. Need to add the new value in a PHP-variable so I can print it on the screen or update my MySQL-database when the button is pressed. I don't want to work in two separate files. Therefore I used a POST-variable.

Below you have my code that I come up with so far (save it to a PHP-file):

```
<?php

echo '
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style>
  #sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; }
  #sortable li { margin: 0 3px 3px 3px; padding: 0.4em; padding-left: 1.5em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; }
  #sortable li span { position: absolute; margin-left: -1.3em; }
</style>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<ul id="sortable">';

$array = str_split("ABCDEFGHI", 3);

for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
  echo '<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>' . $array[$i] . '</li>';
}

echo '
</ul><br>

<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Show order">
</form>

</body>
</html>';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  // How to print the new order value?
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a hidden input field as an array, then when you submit the form, you will have the newly sorted values:

for your `<li>`:

```
echo '<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>' . $array[$i] . '<input type="hidden" name="pos[]" value="'.$array[$i].'"></li>';
```

to dump out the results:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    foreach($_POST['pos'] as $value){
        echo $value.'<br>';
    }
    echo '<pre>',print_r($_POST['pos']),'</pre>';
}
```

As the `li` get shuffled around, the `key` for `pos` will always change. And upon submit, they will order themselves in the way that they are retrieved (from top to bottom).

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply Samuel Cook. I replaced with the code you gave me. 

Changed from:
echo '<pre>',print_r($_POST['pos']),'</pre>';

To:
echo '<pre>'.print_r($_POST['pos']).'</pre>';

But when I press the button it says:
Notice: Undefined index: pos in /XXXXXXX/ on line 43

Comment: two things. 1, Your echo statement won't work on your `print_r` (use the commas to keep on one line). 2, You need to move your `form` tag above the `#sortable ul`. This way it encompasses all of the `input` tags

Comment: I like `sortable` have fun!

Comment: Do you know how I can use the variable to update a MySQL-database? I read somewhere that I can make a query in the foreach section. But how can I use it outside the foreach section to update the database?